# Is there a way to do pattern matching with sass or another css templating language?

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to have the images of a playing card displayed with CSS.  But it would be great if there was a templating language that could set up a style like:

```
.playing-card-(.*) {
   width: 30px
   height: 40px
   background-image: "/images/cards/$1.gif"
}
```

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Does this help http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp ?

Comment: Would you be happy with a solution that lets you generate something like the above, but by looping over a fixed set of values?

Answer (score 1):

I'd love for this to exist but where I've had to do simular tasks I've had to rely on the server side to write the `background-image` as an inline style or use JS to do it (eg if I'm loading the data via AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any CSS technology that will do this for you.  Though it's not ideal, you can use jQuery to achieve this:

I would start by assigning a common class to each card "cards", then using jQuery to iterate through each item, assigning the appropriate CSS to the element.

```
$('.cards').each(function(index,element) {
  $(element).css('background-image','url(images/cards/'+index+'.gif)');
});
```